# Как сверстать адаптивно? Блок с текстом между двумя фотографиями

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужно адаптивно сверстать вот такую секцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше поступить? Задать абсолютно вместе с синим фоном или как?

```
background: url('/img/bg1.jpg') no-repeat top center;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 200px 0 250px 0;
background-size: cover;
```